# Cannot bulk load because the file(type mismatch or invalid character for the specified code)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle-sqldeveloper, bulkinsert

Unable to  insert following Text.csv file which contains

ID,Address,Name,Subject
1,43-79,NYC, Aron , Works for IT,Networking
2, 43-89,CA ,Mike , Works for IT,Developer

How can i insert this data into SQL table(tabl1) which has ID,ADDRESS,NAME,SUBJECT column.

```
BULK  
INSERT tabl1  
FROM 'C:\Downloads\Test.csv'  
WITH  
(  
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'  
)  
GO
```

If i use comma , i get an error.So how can i insert this data.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to the comma in the column value **'Works for IT,Networking'**
You can use Pipe symbol `|` instead of comma.

Sample file will be like this.

```
1|43-79|NYC|Aron|Works for IT,Networking
2|43-89|CA|Mike|Works for IT,Developer
```

Sql Query

```
BULK
INSERT tabl1
FROM 'C:\Downloads\Test.csv'
WITH
(
DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```